# Extracting integers from a list of special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list in python

`a = ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ']']`.

I want to extract integers form this, so that I can get a new list 
 `[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]`. I am using python 3.x and I have tried the solution given in the link [How to extract numbers from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307848/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-list-of-stringsover) but unfortunately I am getting an empty list `[]`. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `t = [int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit()]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract numbers from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307848/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you out, please consider accepting one!

Answer (score 7):

Use [**`isdigit`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) with a list comprehension:

```
[int(i) for i in a if i.isdigit()]

# [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone messed up this data really bad. We have the following:

```
a = ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ']']
```

Let's try something

```
b = ''.join(a)
```

Now `b` is `'[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]'`. This looks like a task for [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(b)
```

Et voilà, the list is back: `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`.

To put everything together:

```
import ast

a = ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ']']
result = ast.literal_eval(''.join(a))
```

---

Whoever created this mess of data used a combination of castings to string and list. Check for yourself: `print(str(list(str([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]))))`

Answer (score 0):

If list comprehensions like

```
t = [int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit()]
```

and

```
t = [int(g) for g in filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(),a)]
```

are beyond you, you can use a simpler approach.  Iterate through all items in your source list, try to convert it into an integer, add the result to a list.

If errors occure, it is not an integer and you ignore that element and do not add it to the result list:

```
a = ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', 
     ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ']']

rv = []

for text in a:
    try:
        rv.append(int(text))   # appennd if convertable to int,
    except: # catchall 
        pass                   # else pass

print(rv)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

ReadUp:

- [error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)
- [filter(function, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) - just for completeness sake if you want to look it up.

Answer (score -2):

A more efficient solution:

```
list(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, a)))
```

Please read [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/6890912). `map` is faster than list comprehension when dealing with non-lambda functions.

Comment: More efficient? This is slower than the list comprehension.

Comment: On a list `10000 * a`: `In [373]: %timeit [int(i) for i in a if i.isdigit()]
35.4 ms ± 259 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: `In [374]: %timeit list(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, a)))
39.7 ms ± 310 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: @user3483203 Not sure what kind of computer you have, but on my laptop, with the same a * 10000 setup, `python -mtimeit "list(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, a)))"` yields `10 loops, best of 3: 70.7 msec per loop`, while `python -mtimeit "[int(i) for i in a if i.isdigit()]"` yields `10 loops, best of 3: 79.4 msec per loop`.

Comment: @user3483203 Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/6890912 `map` is more efficient than list comprehension when dealing with non-lambda functions.